# Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array

Tags: python, arrays

Given an integer array nums sorted in non-decreasing order, remove the duplicates in-place such that each unique element appears only once. The relative order of the elements should be kept the same.

Since it is impossible to change the length of the array in some languages, you must instead have the result be placed in the first part of the array nums. More formally, if there are k elements after removing the duplicates, then the first k elements of nums should hold the final result. It does not matter what you leave beyond the first k elements.

Return k after placing the final result in the first k slots of nums.

Do not allocate extra space for another array. You must do this by modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.
[Here is the examples for the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YI7BM.png)

```
class Solution(object):
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums):
        c = []
    for x in range(len(nums)-1):
        if nums[x] != nums[x+1]:
            c[x] = nums[x]
        self = len(c)
        print(self,c)
```

And I am getting a error that says nums isn't defined but in leetcode it should automatically define it. So why am I getting this error?

Comment: Your code *indentation* is off?

Comment: Just try this - ```return len(set(num))``` - because it's only asking for the final length.

Answer (score 0):

The c list is initialized as an empty list, but it is never used to store any values. Instead, you should modify nums directly. The loop only iterates over the elements of nums up to the second-to-last element, but you need to check the last element as well.The print statement is indented inside the for loop, so it will be executed for each iteration of the loop. This may not be what you intended.

Fix:

```
class Solution(object):
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums):
        i = 0  # Initialize the index
        for j in range(1, len(nums)):
            if nums[j] != nums[i]:
                i += 1
                nums[i] = nums[j] 
        # Return the number of unique elements in nums
        return i + 1

# Test the function
s = Solution()
nums = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5]
print(s.removeDuplicates(nums))  # Output: 5
print(nums)  # Output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```